# Rails 3 migration - 2dc_jqgrid, squirrel - migration options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jqgrid

I have a Rails 2 app that uses [2dc_jqgrid](https://github.com/ahe/2dc_jqgrid) and thus [squirrel](https://github.com/thoughtbot/squirrel) to build [jqgrids](http://www.trirand.com/blog/).

Now looking to move to Rails 3, but I see that squirrel is not coming over.

[ http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/687890317/the-road-to-rails-3 ]

It seems that squirrel is mainly used for paginate by 2dc_jqgrid.

There are some alternate branches for 2dc_jqgrid - some even labelled rails3 - hopefully one of them will do.

So, any tips/clues on the best way to find the right branch...

Thanks in advance, Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this fork might be Rails 3 compatible...

https://github.com/darmou/2dc_jqgrid

Comment: Hi Chris, did you have any success with the darmou plugin? Is there any rails3 compatible jqgrid plugin?????

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember - I think I let the app die instead :(  - it was a small toy app and had issues processing the volume of data I pushing at it.

Comment: Thanx Chris, no issues... :)

Answer (score 2):

rails3 compatible jqgrid plugins:

https://github.com/doabit/jqgrid-rails3

https://github.com/davebaldwin/jqgrid-rails3 (detailed usage)

https://github.com/springbok/jqgrid-rails3